# Defining the amount of words allowed to be submitted in a text area field

Tags: javascript, textarea, cpu-word

I have a form with a textarea field. I like to define the amount of words allowed to 150 words.

How do I achieve this with javascript?

```
<form name="main" action="" method="post">
    <label>
    <span class="legend">Details: </span>(Enter a maximum of 150 words)
    <textarea name="description">

     </textarea>
    </label>
    </fieldset>
   <input type="submit" class="search" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

I have the following code that seems to be wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function validate() {
             if (document.forms['main'].detail.value.length > 150)
              {
               document.forms['main'].detail.focus();
              alert("Detail text should be a maximum of 150 characters");
               return false;
            }     
             if (document.forms['main'].faultType[1].checked==true && (document.forms['main'].detail.value).length == 0)
            {
              document.forms['main'].detail.focus();
              alert("Enter some text that describes the fault");
              return false;
            }
             return true;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: 150 **words**?  The code you've got is written to check for length in characters.

Comment: Duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599688/textarea-maxlength-check

Comment: You're looking for something like `myTextArea.text.split(' ').length` to find the number of words.

Comment: You need to count number of spaces not number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Just split your text on `" "`, and count words that way:

```
function validate() {
    var main = document.forms['main'];
    if (main.detail.value.split(' ').length > 150){
        main.detail.focus();
        alert("Detail text should be a maximum of 150 words");
        return false;
    }     
    if (main.faultType[1].checked==true && main.detail.value.length == 0) {
        main.detail.focus();
        alert("Enter some text that describes the fault");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

For example:

```
"Detail text should be a maximum of 150 words".split(' ');
```

Will return a `Array` like this:

```
["Detail", "text", "should", "be", "a", "maximum", "of", "150", "words"];
```

It's length is `9`, which is the amount of words in the string.